# Webhook dm:version:deleted unstable

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have a webhook setup but seems to have some issues with `dm:version:deleted` not always being triggered.
As far as i can see it is active, but most often just does nothing when i delete a file on BIM360.
I also have other webhooks active like `dm:version:added`, `dm:version:moved`, etc.., that all seems to work as they should.

My question might therefore be, are there any different setups in `dm:version:deleted` compared to the other webhooks?

Are there any known issues with the firing of the `dm:version:deleted`?

Would there be another way to detect the deletion of files on BIM360, other than checking all files in a project?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Esban, can you provide me the hook id for the dm:version:deleted event type. So we can investigate internally.

Comment: Hi Jamie, sorry for slow reply. i have a hook id here: 43ba501b-8f91-4999-9a89-2d3e94bac1d7 - to make sure i have also just tried to delete a file in the folder.

Comment: Adding the information I got from our team in regard to this.

Answer (score 0):

BIM360 is using immutable file operations a “file delete” operation is not really deleting a file but is creating a new version of that file/lineage with a specific type

> versions:autodesk.core:Deleted

so you should check for a file modified event and have a look into the type of the new version. Look for

> dm.version.added

events when the file is deleted on your end and not

> dm:version:deleted

events.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to get this implemented later this week and confirm here that it works as it should. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Jaime, Even I was searching for this. Thank you for the details! I see there is custom metadata available: "forge.type" : "versions:autodesk.core:Deleted-1.0" for delete file. Is this how we differentiate between add and delete event? Also for Folder delete how can we differentiate? I see "dm.folder.modified" event is fired when folder is deleted.